# Is there anyway to workout this IRR with pen and paper or do I need a computer?

Tags: bonds

For the following question (part a), do I need a computer to calculate this IRR or can it be done via pen and paper? I have found the sale price at Y10 to be $78.81 and looking at the IRR as the discount rate that makes NPV = 0.

Question a)[image]

Comment: Check with your instructor whether rate tables will be supplied in the exam to help simplify if a calculator is not available.

Comment: The question makes no sense - EVERYTHING mathematical can be done by hand. It just may not be efficient to do. But "do I need a computer for solving some formula" generally has NO as answer, always. Well, you may need a set of computers in the classical sense - people trained in math that go and work on solving the formula. And yes, that is actually where the word comes from. "Computer" was once a job title. That said, your question is trivial enough that any specialized computer knows how to do it - those are called "calculators". That one will speed is up extremely.

Answer (score 1):

x / y = r * 20 / 100

x / 78.81 = r * 20 / 100

x = 15.762r

and

x + y = (2.5 * 20) + 78.81

15.762r + 78.81 = 128.81

r = 3.17 .

Adapted from:

http://www.kbhscape.com/bond.htm .

Basically, the semi-annual non-compounding rate of a bond that redeems at 78.81 is calculated here.

The use of one-coupon would simplify the operations but only show the value of one-coupon received in the algebraic relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a *computer*, but you can't easily do it by hand either. You could use a financial calculator's "bond" function with the following parameters (parameter names are for the TI BA-II):

```
  N =  10
 PV = -100
PMT =  5
 FV =  78.81
```

and solve for `I/Y`, which gives you 3.1656%.

You're essentially calculating the yield of a 10-year bond that pays 5 per year, bought for 100, that gives you 78.81 at the end of the bond term.

Comment: The math behind this is not that hard. But I would need to look it up / derive it again. In the end a simple calculator would be needed as it involves taking powers of 1.05 and/or 1.07. But it would be a short calculation.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to confirm as in our exam we will not have financial calculator access or excel access and the above was a question from a textbook. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @InvestingScientist There may be some simplification for this specific application that I'm not aware of.

Comment: This seems like a typical "financial calculator question" where you solve for PV (78.81) and then I/Y (3.17%) as the answer demostrated. Given IRR isn't multiplicative like CAGR, I don't think there's a shortcut here.

Comment: @xiaomy My thought is if you can cancel out the individual cash flows there may be some closed formula to calculate gain based on initial yield and current yield.